# How to bind css classes to angular2 elements, post-compiling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

If I insert the html code directly in the HTML obviously that the css is noted and the element is correctly displayed.

However, if I try to dinamically create the element in javascript and insert it the css classes won't be recognized.

For example, I've tried:

```
var el = document.createElement("div").setAttribute("class","some_class");

(...).appendChild(el).
```

And `el` does not obey to the css rules set by `some_class`

The only way I've been able to do this is directly change the element properties in javascript:

```
var el = document.createElement("div").style.width = "20px"; //this works

(...).appendChild(el).
```

The element is correctly styled.
Unfortunately I wanted to go by the class names / ids.

So, any idea on how to do this? How exactly can I bind the newly created elements in javascript via **_ngcontent-vkl-6** tags created after angular2 compiling?

Comment: When you compile, Angular adds attributes properties to your template elements, and use those attributes in the css templates (inspect the elements of your html page to see) 

To add classes to those elements, you have to create a css file, and declare it in your angular cli json file under the scripts property

Answer (score 0):

Use `Renderer` or `Renderer2` (if using angular 4+):

```
constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

createElement() {

 const element = this.renderer.createElement(theElementToAppendTo, 'div');

  this.renderer.setElementAttribute(element, 'class', 'some_class');
}
```

The way you're doing it isn't safe for angular, DOM manipulation should only be done via the `Renderer` or other bindings such as `HostBinding`.

This example uses the `Renderer`:

https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/Renderer-class.html

But if you're using angular 4+ you should use `Renderer2` which has a different api:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/Renderer2-class.html

I hope this helps.